# New to Electronics: How to connect these sparkfun sensors to this radio?

Tags: sensor, radio, modem

I'm really new to this electronics thing, but I was curious how to connect this [High Altitude Balloon sensor board](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9944) to [this modem](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/559). I want to think that it will connect easily and that the hardest part will be connecting the battery to both?

Answer (score 4):

Sparkfun has a [tutorial](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/185) that explains in greater detail how to use the High Altitude Sensing Board. Pay special attention to the section called "Radio System".

In the tutorial they use the [XTend 900 1W RPSMA](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9411) radio module instead of the one you selected. A brief look tells me they both speak UART to the uC (please verify before committing to either module), so it should be relatively straightforward to substitute one for the other. Keep in mind that:

1. There might be things like differences in supply voltage -- be sure to check the design and read the datasheet for the parts in detail.
2. It's possible/likely that they are controlled differently over that serial link, so firmware modifications might be in order.
3. The part you chose is out of stock.
4. The part you chose is less well-suited to this application because of issues of range and interference.

Happy flying!